# using math function on an arange

Tags: python, math, python-2.7, numpy

I have a function that I want to apply to an arange:

```
import math
from numpy import arange
x = arange(7.0,39.0,0.0001)
fx = math.exp(-2.0 / (-14.4 + 19.33 * x - 0.057 * pow(x,2)))
```

The resulting error is as follows:

```
`TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`
```

I am using Python 2.7.

This pythonic approach seems like it should work, but it does not.  What do I need to do to make `fx` contain the corresponding f(x) values, according to the equation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Numpy's [`exp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html) instead of `math`'s:

```
>>> from numpy import arange, exp
>>> x = arange(7.0,39.0,0.0001)
>>> fx = exp(-2.0 / (-14.4 + 19.33 * x - 0.057 * pow(x,2)))
>>> fx
array([ 0.98321018,  0.98321044,  0.98321071, ...,  0.99694082,
        0.99694082,  0.99694083])
```

Numpy's version plays nice with Numpy ndarrays such as `x`. It also has Numpy's performance benefits, which in this case are an order of magnitude compared to the [`vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) `math.exp` solution:

```
# built-in Numpy function
In [5]: timeit exp(-2.0 / (-14.4 + 19.33 * x - 0.057 * pow(x,2)))
100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 ms per loop
# vectorized math.exp function
In [6]: fx = np.vectorize(lambda y: math.exp(-2.0 / (-14.4 + 19.33 *  - 0.057 * pow(y,2))))
In [7]: timeit fx(x)
1 loops, best of 3: 221 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I needed.  And thanks for the performance comparison to `vectorize`, as I really do consider performance.

Answer (score 4):

In general case, you have to [vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) your function to be applicable to np.array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = arange(7.0,39.0,0.0001)
>>> fx = np.vectorize(lambda y: math.exp(-2.0 / (-14.4 + 19.33 * y  - 0.057 * pow(y,2))))
>>> fx(x)
array([ 0.98321018,  0.98321044,  0.98321071, ...,  0.99694082,
        0.99694082,  0.99694083])
```

or, as mentioned @mtitan8, use numpy's vectorized analogue.

As corretly pointed out by @abarnert, if you should always strive for numpy equivalent when possible, as it will  outperform function vectorized by hand.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you should always look for a NumPy equivalent when possible; using `vectorize` gives you the convenience of a real vectorized function, but not the performance. Still, when there _is_ no real vectorized function, it's worth knowing how to do this, so +1.